# Finding the path of the current firebase modification caused by an exterior program

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase (realtime database) together with an application and at some point the values of the database are modified by the app. To catch this modification I added a listener as a Firebase function. The code would look like this:

```
exports.chooseWordsGeneration = 
  functions.database.ref("roomsTest").onWrite((change, context) => {
    // Get the path of the modification in the database
});
```

Together with the database

[image: Current database]

So for example if the app modifies the value of test2, I want to be able to catch the entire path thus "34/test2". In other words I want to know which room was modified. I tried working with the variable `change` given as argument in the `onWrite` but I was not very sucessful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to easily "catch the entire path thus '34/test2'"  you have to listen to the sub-sub-nodes of `roomsTest`, as follows:

```
exports.chooseWordsGeneration = functions.database
  .ref('roomsTest/{roomId}/{testId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log(context.params.roomId + '/' + context.params.testId);
    //....
    return false;  //to adapt
  });
```

Note that `change.after.val()` will then give you the value of the `testId` node.

Comment: This gives me a TypeError, because you need to use `change.before` or `change.after` to have `DataSnapshot` type ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)). But even using this `change.before.ref.key` returns me the main node (roomsTest) thus using parent will lead me to a null result

Comment: @Rekopx You are right, my mistake, we have to use change.after. However, I've totally updated my answer, because actually you have to listen to the sub-sub-nodes of `roomsTest`.